# Не могу UPDATE атрибут в базе данных php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Ниже показана кода php которая отвечает за UPDATE атрибута в базе данных при нажатии на кнопку.
По умолчанию  `status` = '1' (Не скрыто)
При нажатии на   Array('text' => 'Скрыть', 'callback_data' => '/hide/'.$advert_id.'/'),   статус меняется успешно на `status` = '1' (Скрыто)

Но при нажатии на  Array('text' => 'Обновлено', 'callback_data' => '/new/'.$advert_id.'/'),   статус не меняется на 2, и ничего не происходит.
Подскажите в чём проблема?
В настройках БД или в коде?

```
<?
    if($advert['status'] == -1) $status = 'Скрыто';
    if($advert['status'] == 1) $status = 'Не скрыто';
    if($advert['status'] == 2) $status = 'Обновлено';

                    array_push($keyboard['inline_keyboard'], Array(
                        Array('text' => 'Скрыть', 'callback_data' => '/hide/'.$advert_id.'/'),
                        Array('text' => 'Показать', 'callback_data' => '/see/'.$advert_id.'/'),
                        Array('text' => 'Обновить', 'callback_data' => '/new/'.$advert_id.'/'),
                    ));


            if(preg_match('/\/hide\/(\d+|[a-z0-9]{24})\//', $callback['type'])) {
                $advert_id = mb_substr($callback['type'], 6, -1);
                mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `adverts` SET `status` = '-1' WHERE `advert_id` = '$advert_id'");
                send($config['token'], 'answerCallbackQuery', Array('callback_query_id' => $callback['id'], 'text' => 'Вы скрыли задание'.$advert_id, 'cache_time' => 0));
                send($config['token'], 'editMessageText', Array('chat_id' => $callback['from'], 'message_id' => $callback['message_id'], 'text' => getAdvert($callback['from'], $advert_id), 'parse_mode' => 'HTML', 'disable_web_page_preview' => TRUE, 'reply_markup' => getAdvert($callback['from'], $advert_id, 1)));
            }
if(preg_match('/\/new\/(\d+|[a-z0-9]{24})\//', $callback['type'])) {
                $advert_id = mb_substr($callback['type'], 6, -1);
                mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `adverts` SET `status` = '2' WHERE `advert_id` = '$advert_id'");
                send($config['token'], 'answerCallbackQuery', Array('callback_query_id' => $callback['id'], 'text' => 'Вы обновили задание '.$advert_id, 'cache_time' => 0));
                send($config['token'], 'editMessageText', Array('chat_id' => $callback['from'], 'message_id' => $callback['message_id'], 'text' => getAdvert($callback['from'], $advert_id), 'parse_mode' => 'HTML', 'disable_web_page_preview' => TRUE, 'reply_markup' => getAdvert($callback['from'], $advert_id, 1)));
            }

  ?>
```

Comment: во первых, что значит ничего не происходит? Ветка кода выполняется соответствующая? Вывести значения переменных вы можете, чтобы проверить? mb_substr какие параметры получает? Зачем тут вообще эта функция, если ответ можно получить в preg_match ? копипаст зло. еще хуже бездумный копипаст

Comment: это всё в боте функционирует, я в этом профан немного, просто скрипт переделываю под свои нужды, без mb_substr не работает бот правильно

Comment: 6 на 5 замените, может заработает.